# Why i cant use static method from my main?

Tags: java, static, args

i'm making a diary program.

1. In Diary class i made method called "addStudent"
   But i cant figure out why it is invisible in my main?

**EDIT** i added code, sorry for just one block and not 3 but lombok imports are causing issues with formatting

**EDIT2** i deleted remaining questions

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data

public class Diary {


        List<Student> listOfStudents = new ArrayList<>();



    public static void addStudent(Student... students){
        Student student = new Student(Student.askAboutGrades(), Student.askAboutIndexNumber(), Student.askAboutName(), Student.askAboutSurname());

    }
}



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data

public class Student {
    List<Double> grades = new ArrayList<>();
    String indexNumber;
    String name;
    String surname;

    public  static String askAboutName() {
        System.out.println("Type the name");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        while
        (!(name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))) {
            System.out.println("incorrect name, try again");
            name = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Name seems good");
        return name;
    }

    public static String askAboutSurname() {
        System.out.println("Type the surname");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String surname = scanner.nextLine();
        while (!(surname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))) {
            System.out.println("incorrect surname, try again");
            surname = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("surname seems good");
        return surname;
    }

    public static String askAboutIndexNumber() {
        System.out.println("Type the index number (6 digits!)");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String indexNumber = scanner.nextLine();
        while (!indexNumber.matches("\\d{6}")) {
            System.out.println("incorrect index number, try again");
            indexNumber = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("index seems good");
        return indexNumber;
    }

    public static List<Double> askAboutGrades() {
        System.out.println("Type the grades,separated by comma (\",\")");//todo check if works and set limiter from 2 to 5.5
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        String[] arrayOfGrades = input.split(",");
        List<String> listOfGrades = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfGrades));
        List<Double> listOfGradesDouble = new ArrayList<>();
        String temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfGrades.size(); i++) {
            temp = listOfGrades.get(i);
            listOfGradesDouble.add(Double.parseDouble(temp));
        }
        return listOfGradesDouble;
    }
}
```

**Github:**
https://github.com/Karol011/SDA/tree/master/zadania/src/main/java/Kolekcje/ListyKolekcje/Diary

Comment: Please post your code here in the question

Comment: Please post code and not links to code (or images of code).

Comment: Apart from all above, please ask one question per post please. Don't ask multiple questions in single post

Comment: More on what @PradeepSimha pointed out: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735)

Comment: @WJS i tried to add code but it just doesnt work well with imports from Lombok, no idea why tho. Give me a sec, i will fix this

Comment: @Pshemo its fixed now

Comment: Why are you using lombok? Is it necessary?

Comment: to create constructors and getters. Its quicker and cleaner that way

Comment: I never used lambok so this may be stupid question but since your `main` method is empty what makes you think that `addStudent` isn't "visible" there (what do you mean by that)? Also why is `addStudent` static?

Comment: when i'm starting to type _add_ intellij doesn't suggest _addStudent_ method. So i left it empty for now. It's static because i wan't to call it from main, from "itself" (not sure if this is the right term) and not calling it on object

Comment: What makes you think that eclipse/java compiler should know about `addStudend` method in that place? Lets say that there is some other class which also has that name, how should Java determine body of which method should be executed? To avoid that you need to explicitly state to which class method belongs like `YourClassName.staticMethodName(arguments)` (don't forget to add import to `YourClassNme`).

Comment: Yup, i got it now. Thanks

Comment: you can also import it statically and call like you've tried in the first place https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-import-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoah. I'll try:
 1. How are you calling it? Should be somehing like

```
Diary.addStudent();
```

2. Ehmmm. How do you plan to access non-static list from static method? And why it's static?
3. Sounds weird.
4. Figure out what is static and when to use it. In most cases you don't need it. Also, I would remove all lombok and would try to sort thing out using pure java. IMHO.

Powodzenia)

Comment: Ekhem, such a stupid mistake. I feel like a fool now. Thank you, was trying to call it just by typing method name...
Its static because i want to call it from "itself" not from object

Comment: @santana011 so if you insist it should be static, then, probably, you might want to make list static. However, imho I see no reason it has to be static.

Comment: I thought about it for a while and you are right. It makes no sense to make it static, changed it.